Are integers conservatively embedded in the field of complex numbers?
I am looking for a reference to the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is conservatively embedded into the field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers, that is anything in $\mathbb{Z}$ which is definable in $(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ is already definable in $(\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$.

Would this follow from the fact that the integers were already fixed pointwise by all the automorphisms of $\Bbb C$, so the predicate is also fixed?

@AsafKaragila This does not follow. E.g., consider the same argument with $\mathbb R$ in place of $\mathbb C$.

@Emil: I don't see why every real number is fixed by all automorphisms of $\Bbb C$. At least assuming the Axiom of Choice, which I'm assuming is the case here. Otherwise, work in $L$ and use the fact that the whole thing is $\Pi^1_2$ or so.

@AsafKaragila I wrote $\mathbb R$ in place of $\mathbb C$, not  $\mathbb R$ in place of $\mathbb Z$. Every automorphism of $\mathbb R$ fixes $\mathbb Z$, but it is certainly not true that all subsets of $\mathbb Z$ definable in $(\mathbb R,\mathbb Z,+,\cdot)$ are definable in $(\mathbb Z,+,\cdot)$, as $(\mathbb R,\mathbb Z,+,\cdot)$ is biinterpretable with the second-order arithmetic  $(\mathcal P(\mathbb Z),\mathbb Z,+,\cdot,\in)$ (while keeping the $\mathbb Z$ part absolute).

@Emil: But the reals, as a field, are not categorical in their cardinality, it's not the same at all. Move to an ultra power, or a sufficiently saturated model.

Your first comment does not mention any such additional properties, but anyway, $(\mathbb C,\mathbb Z,+,\cdot)$ is neither categorical nor even slightly saturated, so I don't see how this would be relevant.

@Emil: $(\Bbb C,+,\times)$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$-categorical. And the only elements stable under all automorphisms are the rationals, which are definable from $\Bbb Z$ anyway. This is my point. Anyway, I had a chat with one of our model theorist who said that to an extent, my argument isn't far off. All that it's missing is to show some QE over the rationals. Which, again, homogeneity should be helpful to get.

Oh, if you meant to treat the structure as two-sorted and eliminating quantifiers from the $\mathbb C$ sort while keeping quantifiers over $\mathbb Z$, then yes, that would of course solve the problem, but this is basically just restating (a generalization of) the question.

I don't know a reference, but here's a (slightly overkill) proof:
It's known that $(\mathbb{Z};+,\times)$ interprets an algebraically closed field $K$ of infinite transcendence degree and characteristic zero, and it's not hard to show that additionally the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow K$ is also definable in $(\mathbb{Z};+,\times)$. This means that for every logic $\mathcal{L}$ which is at least as strong as first-order logic, every $\mathcal{L}$-definable set of integers in $(K;\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ is already $\mathcal{L}$-definable in $(\mathbb{Z};+,\times)$. But $(K;\mathbb{Z},+,\times)\equiv_{\infty,\omega}(\mathbb{C};\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ since e.g. they become isomorphic after forcing with $Col(\omega,2^{\omega})$. Consequently, letting $\mathit{Def}_\mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{M})$ be the set of relations on the structure $\mathfrak{M}$ which are definable in the logic $\mathcal{L}$ and letting $\mathit{Def}_\mathcal{L}^A(\mathfrak{M})$ be the subset of the above consisting of relations contained in a finite power of $A\subseteq\mathfrak{M}$, we have:

If $\mathcal{L}$ is a logic between $\mathsf{FOL}$ and $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$, then $$\mathit{Def}_\mathcal{L}^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{C};\mathbb{Z},+,\times)=\mathit{Def}_\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{Z};+,\times).$$

In particular, taking $\mathcal{L}=\mathsf{FOL}$ answers the question.
This is a bit overkill though! (That said, it's interesting to note that in $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$ there is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ which is second-order-definable over $(\mathbb{C};\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ but is not second-order-definable over $(\mathbb{Z};+,\times)$: using $\mathsf{AD}$ we get a second-order definition of $\mathbb{R}$ in $(\mathbb{C};+,\times)$, and from there we can define the set of integers coding the full second-order theory of $(\mathbb{Z};+,\times)$, at which point we invoke Tarski.)

EDIT: The above argument really shows the following:

$(*)$ If $\mathcal{L}$ is any logic at least as strong as $\mathsf{FOL}$ such that $\equiv_\mathcal{L}$ coarsens $\equiv_{\infty,\omega}$, then the integers are $\mathcal{L}$-conservatively embedded in $(\mathbb{C};\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$.

(Note that actually this goes a bit beyond $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$; e.g. adding a wellfoundedness quantifier to $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$ results in a strictly stronger logic with the same equivalence notion.)
It would also be enough to require instead that $\mathcal{L}$ has the strong downward Lowenheim-Skolem property ("Every structure in a countable language has a countable $\mathcal{L}$-elementary substructure"); moreover, if we do this we don't need to appeal to forcing! The argument is simple: up to isomorphism there is only one FOL-elementary substructure of $(\mathbb{C};\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$, and this substructure is first-order-interpretable in the integers. Hence we get:

$(**)$ If $\mathcal{L}$ is any logic with $\mathcal{L}\ge\mathsf{FOL}$ and having strong dLS, then the integers are $\mathcal{L}$-conservatively embedded in $(\mathbb{C};\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$.

Note that $(**)$ is broader than $(*)$. For instance, assuming large cardinals we get that $(**)$ applies to the forcing-invariant fragment of second-order logic, but this logic is capable of expressing sentences like "The universe is (isomorphic to) a constructible structure, and the lowest-$L$-rank such structure has $L$-cardinality a successor cardinal" which is not $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$-expressible.
On the other hand, $(**)$ doesn't prima facie subsume $(*)$ either since $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$ doesn't have strong dLS - consider any uncountable ordinal. Of course $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$ does have strong dLS in the specific case of interest here, but proving that is essentially just the forcing argument given above. So really the strongest result we get is:

$(\dagger)$ Let $\mathcal{L}$ be any logic which is at least as strong as $\mathsf{FOL}$ and which has strong dLS for $(\mathbb{C};\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$. Then the integers are $\mathcal{L}$-conservatively embedded in the latter structure.

But this isn't very snappy.

Here's a possibly interesting follow-up question which tests the idea that this is in fact "tricky to prove" (which is now asked separately):
Replace $+$ and $\times$ with their relational versions $+_R$ and $\times_R$ (e.g. $+_R=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{C}^3: a+b=c\}$). In the resulting language, consider the substructure with underlying set $X=\{2^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of $\mathbb{C}$. Every element of $X$ is definable in $\mathbb{C}$ so the way it sits inside $\mathbb{C}$ seems plausibly as tame as that for $\mathbb{Z}$. But the interpretation argument above doesn't work since $X$ is "informationally" just $(\mathbb{N};+)$.

Is there a definable relation on $(\mathbb{C};X,+_R,\times_R)$ which lives on $X$ (= is contained in some finite power of $X$) but is not definable in $(X;+_R,\times_R)$ (which is of course just $(X;\times_R)$)?


Wow, this is very nice!

@JoelDavidHamkins Thanks! The intuition is basically the same as in this old answer of mine.

@JoelDavidHamkins I've added a follow-up question you might find interesting.

How do you define $\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb C$ in SOL assuming AD?

@Wojowu The set of numbers not moved by any automorphism. Under AD, the only automorphism is conjugation.

Or if you prefer an existential second-order definition, the set of numbers which are fixed by some nontrivial automorphism.

Ah right, didn't think you can just quantify over automorphisms. Checks out though.
